# AEM6.5 Passing paramater to the resource from HTL/Sightly template

Tags: aem

I have a component that uses two different resources in its HTL/Sightly template.

Is there a way to pass a parameter, to the say in my example the eventResource template, so that I can depending on this passed paramter change a css class on it?

```
<ul data-sly-list.teasers="${model.resourceList}" class="teaser-list-alternating c-list--reset">
    <sly data-sly-test="${teasers.eventTeaser}"
         data-sly-resource="${teasers.resource @ resourceType='xxx/components/content/eventTeaser'}"></sly>
    <li data-sly-test="${teasers.contentTeaser}" class="l-stack l-stack--horse"
        data-component-hook-content-hub="teaser"
        data-sly-resource="${teasers.resource @ resourceType='xxx/components/content/contentHubTeaser'}"></li>
</ul>
```

I tried using `data-sly-resource="${teasers.resource @ resourceType='xxx/components/content/eventTeaser', requestAttributes=model.config, selectors='blabla'}` to no availability.

```
@RequestAttribute(name = "contentHub")
    private String contentHub;
```

The requestAttribute `contentHub` in the eventTeaser model is alway null and I am not sure how to get the selectors value in the eventTeaser template.

I can do it using TypeScript on the front end part but it is not very clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it using the **selectors** indeed and reading the selector value directly from the other sightly template. [Here](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#229-resource) is the documentation I refered to:

```
data-sly-resource="${teasers.resource @ resourceType='xxx/components/content/eventTeaser', requestAttributes=model.config, selectors='inContentHub'}
```

In the eventTeaser template I then used the following:

```
data-sly-set.inContentHub="${'inContentHub' == request.requestPathInfo.selectorString}
```

and depending on the value of the `inContentHub` variable I was able to change the css class which was my ultimate goal.